# How to wait for the task to getfiles?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
private async Task GetImagesFiles(string radarImagesFolder)
        {
            DirectoryInfo lastRadarWrittenFolder = null;

            var tt = new DirectoryInfo(textBoxRadarPath.Text).GetDirectories();
            if (tt.Length > 0)
            {
                lastRadarWrittenFolder = new DirectoryInfo(textBoxRadarPath.Text).GetDirectories()
                   .OrderBy(d => d.CreationTimeUtc).First();
            }

            if (Directory.Exists(radarImagesFolder) && tt.Length > 0)
            {
               radarImages = Directory.GetFiles(lastRadarWrittenFolder.FullName, "*.png");
            }
        }
```

using it

```
private async void Completed(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e, Stopwatch sw, string urlAddress)
{
  await GetImagesFiles(textBoxRadarPath.Text);
}
```

the problem is in the GetImagesFiles method on it's name GetImagesFiles there is a green line warning :

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Warning CS1998  This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread.    Weather D:\Csharp Projects\Weather\Form1.cs 415 Active

i want to wait to get the files before continue the rest of the code.
once radarImages array is not null and it's length is higher then 0 then continue the rest of the code.

Comment: [Directory.GetFiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=net-7.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) runs synchronously, which means it first finds all the files, then returns the results. It doesn't have any async overload. So  if sync is what you are looking for, just modify the method: remove async keyword, and return files using `Directory.GetFiles`.

Comment: If you want async, then considering that DirectoryGetFiles doesn't have any async overload, you can create an async method which uses Task.Run to get the files in a background thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing async in `GetImagesFiles`, so you can just remove `async Task` from it. This aligns with suggestion from [`Task.Run` Etiquette Examples: Don't Use `Task.Run` in the Implementation](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html) by Stephen Cleary. Also I would move setter out of the `GetImagesFiles` with resulting code looking like:

```
private string[] GetImagesFiles(string radarImagesFolder)
{
    DirectoryInfo lastRadarWrittenFolder = null;

    var tt = new DirectoryInfo(textBoxRadarPath.Text).GetDirectories();
    if (tt.Length > 0)
    {
        lastRadarWrittenFolder = new DirectoryInfo(textBoxRadarPath.Text).GetDirectories()
            .OrderBy(d => d.CreationTimeUtc).First();
    }

    if (Directory.Exists(radarImagesFolder) && tt.Length > 0)
    {
         return Directory.GetFiles(lastRadarWrittenFolder.FullName, "*.png");
    }

    return null;
}
```

And invocation:

```
private async void Completed(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e, Stopwatch sw, string urlAddress)
{
    var result = await Task.Run(GetImagesFiles(textBoxRadarPath.Text));
    if(result != null)
    {
        radarImages = result;
    }
}
```

P.S.

Though returning `null` as marker can be a code smell but for brevity and due to lack of knowledge about language version you are using I've went with this approach.